# How to configure a jenkins node to only accept jobs that specifically requested this node via it's label?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I know how to restrict by Job name on the node configuration page:

[image]

But now we have (multibranch pipeline) DSL job scripts that dynamically determine on which node they should run, and request it via `node(label: 'NODE-LABEL') { ... }`.

I would like to restrict one of our nodes (a dedicated mac mini responsible for installer signing) to only accept jobs that specifically requested to be run on that node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node Configuration screen there is option "Usage". This dropdown can be used to set nodes to only accept jobs specifically matching the labels of that node.
[image: Node Usage option example in Jenkins UI]

The rest of it is to set labels for the node so that there are no accidentally jobs running on it due to matching the labels partially.

Comment: Ah yes, completely overlooked that one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use label expressions to determine where jobs will run.

For example all linux agents have a label 'os-linux', all windows agents have a label 'os-windows', agents that are used for general development have a 'builder' label, and agents that are used for code signing would have a 'code-signing' label.

The agents used for general build operations would be configured with labels such as ['os-linux','builder'] and the agent(s) used for code-signing would be configured with labels such as ['os-linux', 'code-signing'], etc.

The pipeline for general development would have agent labels indicating that 'builder' agents are required:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'os-linux && builder' }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      sh "mvn clean deploy"
    }
  }
}
```

And the pipeline for code signing would have a pipeline indicating that an agent capable of code-signing is required:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'os-linux && code-signing' }
  stages {
    stage('Sign') {
      withCredentials(...) {
        sh "java codesign.jar -keystorePassword=..."
      }
    }
}
```

or in this case the DSL would be:

```
node(label:'os-linux && code-signing') {
  ...
}
```

This allows you to have multiple builder agents, multiple code-signer agents, etc, and you can partition the agents accordingly.